# Why is TensorFlow's tf.data.Dataset.shuffle so slow?

Tags: tensorflow

The `shuffle` step in the following code works very slow for a moderate buffer_size (say 1000):

```
filenames = tf.constant(filenames)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size)
```

If we use `numpy` to shuffle the data, the code looks as follows:

```
idx = np.arange(len(filenames))
np.random.shuffle(idx)
new_filenames = [filenames[i] for i in idx]
next_batch_filenames = new_filenames[:batch_size]
# get the corresponding files in batch
```

This is much faster. I wonder if TF does something beyond simply shuffles the data.

Comment: What is your definition of slow? Also in your TensorFlow code loads files whereas your numpy example doesn't. Might also be relevant: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14857

Comment: I didn't time the program but TF's version is significantly slower. The last line in my numpy block is meant to get files into memory and convert them into TF format. But thx for the link.

Comment: Try using prefetch option after shuffling. It should make loading faster. Ex: dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=10)

Comment: My understanding is that TensorFlow shuffle actually makes copies of the elements over which can become painfully slow if you don't have enough RAM to hold them.

Comment: In 2019 with tf 1.14 cuda 10, for a training set of 84519 samples with resizing(224,224,3 from 512 x694) as the only op in the preprocessing, batch size 16 tf.data.Dataset.shuffle(len(train_files)) takes 1 hour 5 min in a GTX 1080 8GB GPU, Intel core i7  7820 HK 8 cores CPU it takes around one hour to get the data ready at begining.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison is of two quite different operations.

Your `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))` reads from disk.  Like physical long term storage, possibly a magnetic spinning hard drive.  This is slow.  If you have the ability to store all of this in ram instead, or on an ultra fast raid style flash drive, then you'll address your largest bottle neck.

You also have a `_parse_function` that is fired off for each data point, every time there is a data read.  The computation of that parse will take time and depending on what is in there it could be significant.

The comparison to numpy isn't really fair, in that your numpy example doesn't involve reading from disk or parsing data.

That should be the bulk of the difference.  If you've addressed the above, the next place to look for more speedup is with these lines

```
3) dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
4) dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
5) dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size)
```

These are your code lines.  Line 4 makes batches of data, possibly 32 (`batch_size` for sure).  Then line 5 kicks in and tries to shuffle your batches of 32 in a buffer of length 1000.  That happens every time the training loop requests a new training batch.  The shuffle step shuffles all those big batches, picks out the first one and adds a new one ... every ... single ... time.

We can reverse the order of batch and shuffle like so

```
3) dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
4) dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size)
5) dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

This is better anyway, because before the contents of the batches were always the same but the order was mixed.  This way the contents of the batches will be randomized also.  Next, the shuffle has to only shuffle 1000 items, not 32x1000 items.  Last, we can challenge if we really need a buffer size of 1000.  Let's say our data set is 2000 items.  A buffer size of 320 and a batch size of 32 will certainly randomize our data well, effectively giving any data in the buffer a 10% of going into the next batch and a 90% of being pushed back to mix with other data.  That's pretty good.  A buffer size of 64 and a batch size of 64 seems almost useless, other than the items are pulled out of the batch randomly one at a time, and so actually have a chance of not getting drawn and mixing with later data.  Just not so much.

Comment: First time I hear that smaller buffer size is better

Answer (score 1):

As Anton Codes wrote, your first snippet shuffles batches of whatever `_parse_function` parses from your files (probably feature data), while your second snippet only shuffles filenames.

If shuffling on file level is sufficient, you can actually achieve (roughly) the same performance via the `tf.data.Dataset` API:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(filenames)) # shuffle file names
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

This practice of **shuffling "pointers" to your training samples instead of the samples themselves** can often improve performance.

NumPy might still be a little bit more efficient though, due to the overhead of shuffling inside the computational graph (which `tf.data.Dataset.shuffle` does, there is actually a C++ kernel specifically for this operation).

The advantage of the `tf.data.Dataset` approach is that it can automatically reshuffle the Dataset after each epoch.